# Displaying datetime at midnight as datetime, not as date using R

Tags: r, datetime

I have two variables in R, lets say for example:

```
from <- as.POSIXct('2022-06-25 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz='UTC')
```

and

```
to <- as.POSIXct('2022-06-25 14:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz='UTC')
```

I want to display! both in **datetime** format, e.g. in a dataframe or in my variable-environment in R studio or when exporting this value as csv or xlsx. The second one `to` always displays correct as its not at midnight, but the first one `from` always displays as `2022-06-25`, so as a date, but not as datetime. Calculations are correct, so its just a display issue. How can I force R to display this value including time? Minimal example:

```
from <- as.POSIXct('2022-06-25 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz='UTC')
to <- as.POSIXct('2022-06-25 14:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz='UTC')
data <- data.frame(x1 = 1:5)
data <- cbind(to = to, data)
data <- cbind(from = from, data)
data 
view(data)
```

Comment: When you print things to the console, R tries to make them look pretty. If a date/time value has the time at midnight, R will just print it as a date by default. If you need control over the formatting of columns, then you should use the explicit `format()` function rather than the defaults from the implicit `print()` function for data.frames. Or you could use an alternative container like a tibble which has it's own printing function: `tibble::tibble(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `format` to force arbitrary display formats for `POSIXct or POSIXt` vectors:

```
format(data,format="%Y-%m%-%d %T")
                 from                  to x1
1 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  1
2 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  2
3 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  3
4 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  4
5 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  5
```

Unfortunately AFAICS there is no default way to make this, but you can write a custom print function that does this:

```
print_with_time <- function(df, ...)
{
  df <- data
  timeCols <- which(sapply(df,inherits,"POSIXt"))
  for(i in timeCols)
  {
    df[[i]] <- format(df[[i]],format="%Y-%m-%d %T")
  }
  base::print.data.frame(df, ...)
}

> print_with_time(data)
                 from                  to x1
1 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  1
2 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  2
3 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  3
4 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  4
5 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  5
```

Now, if you really want that to happen by just calling `print` on a `data.frame` you *can* overwrite the default S3 method dispatch target `print.data.frame` with this function. But beware this might lead to unexpected results elsewhere:

```
print.data.frame <- print_with_time
> print(data)
                 from                  to x1
1 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  1
2 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  2
3 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  3
4 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  4
5 2022-06-25 00:00:00 2022-06-25 14:00:00  5
```

Comment: To add the command to view the df: `view(format(data,format="%Y-%m%-%d %T"))`. A setting in R Studio to change that default behavior would be nice.

Comment: @MrXsquared I've added a function to make this "default". But beware the consequences :)